# Why can't Linked Style types be changed?

Tags: microsoft-word

Scott Basham. [*Word 2019 in easy steps*](http://ineasysteps.com/products-page/all_books/word-2019-easy-steps/). p. 55.

> [image]

Kindly see the Hot Tip tabled in red.

Comment: I would have assumed this was spam for the linked book, except you've been a member for awhile and have other posts.  What is your question, and who is Scott Basham?  If this is intended as a self-answered question, a "why" question in the title isn't one.  You would need to present a problem with some context as a question, and the solution as an answer.  Quoting a source can be a citation to support your answer.  (cont'd)

Comment: In general, sharing a tidbit you found somewhere isn't really the intended purpose of the site.  It is for actual problems you face (which should be presented that way).  If this is intended to refute an answer somewhere, post it as a comment on that answer.  It's likely to attract downvotes as-is.

Comment: @fixer1234 To be clear, no, I'm no way linked to him. I'm uncertain why you "would have assumed this was spam for the linked book"? I'm trying to learn from this book, and am asking a question.

Comment: From your time on the site and other posts, I assumed you weren't a spammer, but we get a lot of spam with this general pattern.  It looks like there's no real problem you're trying to solve, just a "why" question in the title and no obvious reason why it's being asked.  Then the question body appears to show the answer, and adds a retail link to a book.  So it looks like a flimsy excuse to hawk the book (i.e., the spam pattern).  The site isn't really set up for general learning, it's more for solving specific problems.  (cont'd)

Comment: "Why" questions often come down to development decisions none of us is privy to, so they tend to attract opinion-based answers.  The question title is just context to orient the reader to what you will be talking about.  The question should contain the actual question.  Try to frame it as a specific problem or issue you need to solve.  If in trying to solve it, you encounter some advice that doesn't seem to make sense, add that to the question, and why it doesn't make sense.  (cont'd)

Comment: Then ask for a solution to the problem, or an explanation of how things work, and clarification on the unclear advice you cite.  It sounds like what you want to know (i.e., help learning Word), isn't a great fit for the site, so it may be a challenge to frame this as a good, on-topic question.

Comment: I was just looking at your question trying to figure out a way to reframe it.  But I think the answer is "because that's how Microsoft designed it".  They decided that paragraph styles can have their type changed and linked styles can't.  There isn't really much people here can add to that.  It's the way Microsoft chose to implement Word.